# mutation reference for Box closure, but not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm rather new to rust, I have some problems,I don't know how to describe my problem. I think talk is cheap and I want to show my code, but I must add more detail for post.

```rust
// programA
struct ClosureTest {
  x: u8,
}

type Executor = Box<dyn FnMut() -> ()>;

impl ClosureTest {
  fn new(x: u8) -> Self {
    ClosureTest { x }
  }
}

struct Ftest {}

impl Ftest {
  fn exec(&self, mut executor: Executor) {
    executor();
  }
}

fn receive_test(arg: &mut ClosureTest) {
  arg.x = 6;
  println!("{}", arg.x);
}

fn main() {
  let mut closure_test = ClosureTest::new(5);
  let f_test = Ftest {};
  let executor = Box::new(|| {
    receive_test(&mut closure_test);
  });

  f_test.exec(executor);
}
```

I got these errors:

```rust
error[E0597]: `closure_test` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:30:23
   |
29 |   let executor = Box::new(|| {
   |                           -- value captured here
30 |     receive_test(&mut closure_test);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
33 |   f_test.exec(executor);
   |               -------- cast requires that `closure_test` is borrowed for `'static`
34 | }
   | - `closure_test` dropped here while still borrowed
```

But if I use mut reference like follows, it works fine.

```
// programB
struct ClosureTest {
  x: u8,
}

type Executor<'a> = &'a mut dyn FnMut() -> ();

impl ClosureTest {
  fn new(x: u8) -> Self {
    ClosureTest { x }
  }
}

struct Ftest {}

impl Ftest {
  fn exec(&self, executor: Executor) {
    executor();
  }
}

fn receive_test(arg: &mut ClosureTest) {
  arg.x = 6;
  println!("{}", arg.x);
}

fn main() {
  let mut closure_test = ClosureTest::new(5);
  let f_test = Ftest {};
  let mut executor = || {
    receive_test(&mut closure_test);
  };

  f_test.exec(&mut executor);
}
```

So

1. What's the reason cause this difference.
2. Why in sync program "programA" will cause lifetime error?
3. closure_test is drop before f_test.exec(executor)? or after?

Comment: I don't think I can give enough detail to write an answer, but I'm pretty sure the static requirement comes from trying to heap allocate (`Box` is on the heap) a reference. If you allow the `Box` to take ownership with the `move` keyword, then example A works also: `Box::new(move || { receive_test(&mut closure_test); });`.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows add move is working, but I still want to know how to fix programA by lifetime. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what is happening here you'll need to make a little dive into the Rust Book and learn about [lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime.html).

I'll simplify for sake of explanation and comment this:

```
//type Executor = Box< dyn FnMut() -> ()>;
```

And change the signature of exec function to this:

```
fn exec(&self, mut executor: Box<dyn FnMut() -> () >) {
    executor();
}
```

First of all let's notice that if we will comment very last line:

```
//f_test.exec(executor);
```

the error is gone. The reason for this is that reference to the closure you created - &Box<dyn FnMut() -> ()> has shorter lifetime than other part of main (it's scoped). It means that when you are creating this closure it exists, but just after the reference to this is dropped. That's why it doesn't complain if you not use it, because it's all okay.

Lifetimes are not variables, they are claims, kinda of similar to generics.
If you would change right now the signature of function exec function to this:

```
impl Ftest {
    fn exec<'a>(&self, mut executor: Box<dyn FnMut() -> () + 'a>) {
        executor();
    }
}
```

I would say this:

- let's say that lifetime of my function is a,
- it would takes some parameters and return Box of function which lifetime would be also a, so it would live as long as I.

By doing it we hinted compiler that the lifetime of closure you'll create should live "in same lifetime" as exec() is executed. That's why even if we bring back the last line of main it would work :D.

There is also an option of adding `move` keyword:

```
fn main() {
    let mut closure_test = ClosureTest::new(5);
    let f_test = Ftest {};
    let executor = Box::new(move || {
        receive_test(&mut closure_test);
    });

    //println!("{}", closure_test.x);
    f_test.exec(executor);
}
```

This will work, because by adding `move` keyword we actually tell that we would rather move closure_test object to our scope, not just a reference, therefore it's not dropped. However you wouldn't be able to use it later as shown if you'll uncomment the line with println!().

I'll be happy if anybody would provide some corrections and more details. This concept in Rust is unique and takes time to fully understand so it would be helpful.